# address validation global solution

Tags: c#

suppose user fillup form with germany address but as country choose UK. so how can i validate address there like if user choose country UK then i want that user has to write UK address for other detail. how to do it for all country. is there any IP available. need idea. thanks

Comment: Far as I know, you pretty much can't reliably determine if an address is valid just by analyzing it. You could come close if you restricted the possible countries and formats, but even within a single country there will be different ways to specify an address and enumerating them all would be difficult at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without full details of the formats of addresses of both countries (and if you have to support more, your would need the details of each country), you will not be able to validate properly.

Even with this detail, some countries will have such similar formats that you will not be able to tell which one the address belongs to.

Your best bet is to use an address verification library/service.

Comment: is there any address verification library or service available for .net.....i search google but found none.

Comment: @user728750 - Google is your friend: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=address+verfication+library+.net#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=address+verfication+library+.net+-email&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=a19d57c9b1bb4a83&biw=1280&bih=939

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that describe a lot of international postal address formats: [International Mailing Address Formats](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html)

Otherwise, there are companies that make a business out of this process (technically, they propose Web Services for this).